# data transfer for iPad app

Tags: applications, data-transfer, ipad

How do I extract the data for a single app to transfer to another device running the same app? I want to move a personal wiki from an iPad 1 to an iPad 3.

Comment: What is the app in question?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy any file from and to your ipad manually using a software tool like [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com) without the need for jailbreaking. 
I use iFunBox to backup save-games and app settings.

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer depends somewhat on the app in question, however there are several apps available which will make your iOS device ‘browse-able’ from your Mac or PC.

iExplorer (Mac or PC)
http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/

PhoneView (Mac only)
http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/

iFunBox (Windows only)
http://i-funbox.com